# ¿Cómo mostrar un mensaje cada que un contador llega a 20?

Tags: python

estoy intentando tabular una lista, pero como tiene muchos items, quiero que cada que mi contador llegue a 20 muestre el header nuevamente, les muestro mi código:

```
    index_linea = 1
    correo, nombre, nacimiento, monto, folio, momento = darFormato(0)
    print("-"*122)
    print ("{:<20} {:<20} {:<20} {:<20} {:<20} {:<20}".format(correo, nombre, nacimiento, monto, folio, momento))
    print("-"*122)
    for linea in range(len(lista_datos) -1):
        correo, nombre, nacimiento, monto, folio, momento = darFormato(index_linea)
        print ("{:<20} {:<20} {:<20} {:<20} {:<20} {:<20}".format(correo, nombre, nacimiento, monto, folio, momento))
        index_linea += 1
        if index_linea == 20:
            correo, nombre, nacimiento, monto, folio, momento = darFormato(0)
            print("-"*122)
            print ("{:<20} {:<20} {:<20} {:<20} {:<20} {:<20}".format(correo, nombre, nacimiento, monto, folio, momento))
            print("-"*122)
    input("**Presiona ENTER para regresar al menú principal...")
    return False
```

Como se ve, sólo tengo un if verificando si es igual a 20, pero no logro entender cómo hacer la comprobación si es cada 20 (20, 40, 60, 80, 100...).

Muchas gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: Y si pones if `index_linea % 20 == 0:`? Cada vez que la división entre 20 sea 0 devolverá `True`.

Comment: Hola @AdriánSanzWallace me ha funcionado tu solución. ¿Puedes ponerla como respuesta para marcarla como correcta? Por favor.

Comment: Ya la tienes respondida!

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar el **operador módulo** (`%`), que te devuelve el resto de una división.

Generalmente lo verás en ejemplos utilizado para saber si un numero es par, de la forma `n%2==0`, que de cumplirse el numero será par y en caso contrario impar.

Te pongo un ejemplo de su uso, para que veas lo que hace:

```
lista_inicial = [5, 10, 15, 20, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55, 60]

print([val for val in lista_inicial if val % 20 == 0])
# Devuelve [20, 40, 60]

print([val for val in lista_inicial if val % 2 == 0])
# Devuelve [10, 20, 40, 50, 60]

print([val for val in lista_inicial if val % 5 == 0])
# Devuelve [5, 10, 15, 20, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55, 60]
```